# Taking a screenshot with a Unity player in a website

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I'm currently trying to create a function that takes a screenshot of my page and saves it as a png file. Problem is, I've tried most functions such as imagegrabscreen, htmlcanvas, gitz etc. but it doesn't seem like its detecting the unity webgl player that I've placed. It only takes a screenshot of the css/html scripts on my website. Are there any ways to work on this?

Here's the code of my unity that I wanted to screen shot and save as a png along with the button below the unity player to call the screenshot function:

```html
<center><p class="header">Ace Furniture Configurator</p>
    <div class="template-wrap clear">
      <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>
      <br>
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="fullscreen"><img src="TemplateData/fullscreen.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Fullscreen" title="Fullscreen" onclick="SetFullscreen(1);" /></div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
  var Module = {
    TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912,
    errorhandler: null,   // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
    compatibilitycheck: null,
    dataUrl: "Release/unity.data",
    codeUrl: "Release/unity.js",
    memUrl: "Release/unity.mem",
    
  };
</script>
<script src="Release/UnityLoader.js"></script><br><input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot" id="btnscreen" name="btnscreen"></center><br><br>
<!-- //configurator -->
```

The imagegrabscreen function I called with a submit button:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnscreen']))
{
    $img = imagegrabscreen();
    imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found a solution for that, which works for me.
First of all you have to activate the preserveDrawingBuffer for your game instance.
(JavaScript):

```
var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%", {onProgress: UnityProgress,
  Module: {
    webglContextAttributes: {"preserveDrawingBuffer": true},
  }
});
```

After that the rendered image of the canvas is written into the DrawingBuffer and you can simply get it by using the function `.toDataURL()` of your canvas. You can setup different file formats and quality settings for this function if you want (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

So create an `<a>` Tag in html and a click event listener for it in JavaScript like that (HTML):

```
<a class="" id="btn_download-screenshot" download="myScreenshot.jpg">
     Screenshot
</a>
```

Get the canvas element with the WebGL and use the `.toDataURL()` function (JavaScript):

```
$("#btn_download-screenshot").on('click',function(){
   var dataUrl = document.getElementById('gameContainer').childNodes[0].toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
   $(this).attr('href', dataUrl);
});
```

You upload the dataURL, which is the image itself, with AJAX and JavaScript to any sever and save it there if you want.